# Conditional margining for a grid elements in xaml

Tags: xaml, margin, uwp-xaml, conditional-formatting

I have a grid with 2 rows and 4 columns with width and height as specified below. Second row has only one control in col=1 and that control may or may not present(due to some logic).

```
          <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid>
```

**When control is not present:**

Since second row is height is "Auto" and when I have no control, I'll have only single row. In that case, I need to have specific margin with respect to grid bottom.
Hence, ***Margin of row 0 control = "0,0,0,14"***

**When control is present:**

When control is present, I have two rows and I need to have margin between two row elements as 6px and second row margin should be 14 w.r.t bottom of grid.
Hence, ***Margin of row 0 control = "0,0,0,6"*** and Margin of row 1 control = "0,0,0,14"

How could I achieve these different margin values based on second row presence. Please help. Thanks in advance.
Refer img:

[image: Grid image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you could use  `MarginConverter` to set row 0 control margin base on the row 1 control's present or not.

For example

```
public class MarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Thickness newMargin;
        var visibility = (Visibility)value;
        switch (visibility)
        {
            case Visibility.Visible:
                newMargin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 6);

                break;
            case Visibility.Collapsed:
                newMargin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 14);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return newMargin;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
 <Page.Resources>
     <local:MarginConverter x:Key="Conveter" />
 </Page.Resources>
 <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Rectangle
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Margin="{Binding ElementName=Row1Control, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource Conveter}}"
         Fill="Red" />
     <Rectangle
         x:Name="Row1Control"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Height="80"
         Margin="0,0,0,14"
         Fill="Black"
         Visibility="Visible" />
 </Grid>
```

**Update**

> But in my case, Row1Control is dynamically set in the backend.

you could detect RootGrid `LayoutUpdated` event, if you add the control it will be invoked, then re-set MarginProperty in the following method.

```
private int oldCount;
private void RootGrid_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
{
   
    if(RootGrid.Children.Count > oldCount)
    {
        if (RootGrid.Children.Any(p => p.GetValue(NameProperty).ToString() == "Row1Control"))
        {
            Row0Control.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 6));
        }
        else
        {
            Row0Control.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 14));
        }
        oldCount = RootGrid.Children.Count;
    }         
   
}
```

Add element in the code behind.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var Row1Control = new Rectangle() { Height = 80, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 14), Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), Name = "Row1Control" };
    Row1Control.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    Row1Control.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
    RootGrid.Children.Add(Row1Control);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. It is always taking the "Visibility" value as visible and applying "0,0,0,6". But in my case, Row1Control is dynamically set in the backend.